# 400 Bad Request on JWT Authentication

Tags: node.js, http, jwt, postman

What is the root cause of this http 400 Error? Setup is REST API NodeJs +Mysql . So here is a summary of where I am at:

---

1. User successfully signed up
2. JWT tokens successfully generated for user
3. Model done, POST, GET, DELETE etc works fine. If I add JWT
4. Token to JSON input and extract from code, it works fine.
5. But it goes burst when I try to get it from http Headers ***req.Headers.Authorization.split(" ")[1]***

**See key code sections below :**

> ```
>    Module.exports = (req, res, next){
>            const token = req.Headers.Authorization.split(" ")[1];
>           //const token2 = req.body.token;  /*this worked!*/
>                const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
>               req.udata = decoded;
> }
> ```

**Raw body JSON input in Postman is:**

```
> {
>     "project_Id" : 2,
>     "lots" : [
>         {
>             "sn" : "1",
>         "lotname" : "Consultancy Project NASA",
>         "value" : "N10m",
>         "status" : "awarded"
>         },
>         {
>             "sn" : "1",
>         "lotname" : "Consultancy Project NASA",
>         "value" : "N10m",
>         "status" : "awarded"
>         }
>     ],
>     "applicant_Id" : 4,
>     "pitch" : "I am the best, you are will be sorry if you do not take me"  }
```

**And finally, the Postman screen:**

[image]

Comment: please share the screenshot of headers you are passing in the request from postman.

Comment: What is the value of `req.Headers.Authorization`? What do you set the Authorization header in Postman to?